# neo4j load 1000 json documents using apoc

Tags: json, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to load json documents into neo4j which has complex structure...I cannot use csv format...

Can someone please tell how to load 1000+ json documents using apoc?

I know how to load one document trying to find how to load in loop the 1000 documents

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import from  multiple JSON documents serially, you can do something like this (assuming that `urls` is passed to the Cypher query as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)):

```
UNWIND $urls AS url
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value
...
```

If it makes sense to perform the imports concurrently (e.g., there is no risk of [deadlocks](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/transaction-management/deadlocks/) -- because different files would not write-lock the same set of relationships or nodes), you could consider using one of the APOC [periodic execution](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/periodic-execution/) procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your files are in the "import" directory, the following CQL should work:

```
CALL apoc.load.directory()
YIELD value as files
UNWIND files as file
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('
    CALL apoc.load.json($file)
    YIELD value as line
', '
    CREATE (pc:SomeNode{type: line.type}) //Process line here
', {batchSize:10000, parallel:true, params: {file: file}})
YIELD batches, total, updateStatistics
RETURN batches, total, updateStatistics
```